# Choose one of two system attributes

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I need to create configurator which read/write xml configs.
Part of config is in the following form:

```
<camera>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Camera 1</name>
    <address>http://192.168.1.100</address>
    <roi>
        <rect>
            <x>100</x>
            <y>200</y>
            <width>300</width>
            <height>150</height>
        </rect>
        <rect>
            <x>350</x>
            <y>400</y>
            <width>200</width>
            <height>250</height>
        </rect>
    </roi>
</camera>
```

But an output I need in form with xml attributes:

```
<camera id="1" name="Camera 1" address="http://192.168.1.100">
    <roi>
        <rect x="100" y="200" width="300" height="150 />
        <rect x="350" y="400" width="200" height="250 />
    </roi>
</camera>
```

I create a class for every main node, but I was wondering how to choose if property for deserialization should be XmlElement and for serialization should be XmlAttribute. Or have I create two separate classes for first form of xml and for the second one? I am beginner in C# and .NET so also any points and suggestions to do it in other way?

C# code:

```
[System.Serializable()]
public class CamerasConfigAttrib
{
    private int id;
    private string name;
    private string address;
    private Collection<Rectangle> roi;

    [XmlAttribute("id", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    [XmlAttribute("name", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    [XmlAttribute("address", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string Address
    {
        get { return address; }
        set { address = value; }
    }

    [XmlArray("roi", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [XmlArrayItem("rect", typeof(Rectangle), Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified]
    public Collection<Rectangle> Roi
    {
        get { return roi; }
        set
        {
            foreach (var rect in value)
                roi.Add(rect);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have to make two different classes, but if there is better way to do that, it interest me

Comment: You should create an XSLT and use `XslCompiledTransform` to crerate the new XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [XmlAttributeOverrides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides(v=vs.110).aspx) to serialize you object to another structure (you can use it to deserialize also). Here Is a short sample how you can use it in your case:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("camera")]
public class CamerasConfigAttrib : IXmlSerializable
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Process code:

```
// sample data
var xml = @"<camera><id>1</id><name>Camera 1</name></camera>";
// deserialization according to a native attributes
var camera = (CamerasConfigAttrib)new XmlSerializer(typeof(CamerasConfigAttrib))
                 .Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
// prepare overridings
var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
overrides.Add(typeof (CamerasConfigAttrib), "Id",
    new XmlAttributes
    {
        XmlAttribute = new XmlAttributeAttribute("Id")
    });
overrides.Add(typeof(CamerasConfigAttrib), "Name",
    new XmlAttributes
    {
        XmlAttribute = new XmlAttributeAttribute("name")
    });
// serializer initiated with overridings
var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CamerasConfigAttrib), overrides);
var sb = new StringBuilder();
s.Serialize(new StringWriter(sb), camera);
```

Result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<camera xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Id="1" name="Camera 1" />
```

Seems to me this way is more natural, and doesn't require additional classes or files.

As an alternative you can implement interface [`IXmlSerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx), it gives more flexibility but it's a bit more complex